# Chat refuses to log me in; SOPA

Tags: discussion, spam

I was going to put this in the chat room, but SE seems to miss my login credentials when I go to the chat room, so please spirit this to the chat room if possible and appropriate.

I want to encourage the members of the PhysicsSE community that are from the USA to consider writing to their congressional delegations or to sign one of the many petitions circulating the internet today in regards to the SOPA (Stop Online Piracy Act) or PIPA (Protect IP Act).  As written, these bills are vague, and potentially harmful to the internet as a whole.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), perhaps the most linked to site on this very SE, has gone dark in protest. The [EFF has identified a number of potential consequences](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/01/how-pipa-and-sopa-violate-white-house-principles-supporting-free-speech), including potential severe restrictions on software distribution, and collaborative sites like this one.  I challenge members of the community to consider what would happen to a site like PhysicsSE, and the impact on your research and studies if these bills become law.

Comment: Been (and being) discussed at length on the mother meta.